# Samba Ubuntu 20.04 -> Windows slow transfer speeds

Tags: networking, server, samba, windows-10, ethernet

I recently upgraded my media server's hardware and used the opportunity to change OS from windows to Ubuntu. My personal desktop and my media server are both connected to the same router by cat 5e cables. Before upgrading, when I still had windows 10 on my media server, whenever I transferred files from my desktop to the server or vice versa, I'd get around 100-115 MBps transfer speeds. Now, the transfer speeds are really slow compared to the previous speed. Furthermore, even generally, my server's Wifi connections is faster than my ethernet connection (280Mbps vs 89Mbps) while I'm supposed to have 400Mbps which I get when doing a speed test from my desktop when connected by ethernet.

Now, I'm transferring some files to the media server (around 300GB), and the transfer speed is 10-11MBps. The transfer is capped at this speed regardless of whether I'm transferring over WiFi or Ethernet.

What can I do to fix my network issues? Thanks!

Edit: on while troubleshooting, I discovered that my ethernet port is limiting the speed to 100Mbps even though both the port and my router are capable of Gigabit lan. I understand now why my wifi connection is faster than my ethernet connection. I'll edit again once I figure out how to fix this issue

Comment: The issue may be SMB Signing. I just fixed this on my new MacBook Pro using this guide: https://www.qnap.com/en-us/how-to/faq/article/how-do-i-improve-slow-file-transfer-speeds-between-mac-os-10-11-5-and-newer-and-my-nas-via-smb-protocol/?fbclid=IwAR1q9_bNMPx2qL8qkIkqnL3j3Wb3glV5aw-5kCdR9AC5DebkKR3cPJ3HCTU Maybe somethign similar can be done on Ubuntu? I know in the past this issue has plagued me and none of the fixes work. This is the first time I came across the signing features and it restored my speed back to 114MB/s over Ethernet to SMB shares.

Comment: @ScottMyers Thanks for the reply!. Ned to update my post but turns out the ethernet cable that I had assembled was not 100% functional and it was the reason my speeds were reduced. Crimping a new rj45 jack fixed it. Either way, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a faulty ethernet cable which was limiting my speeds. Changing the faulty rj45 connector fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Try these samba tweaks to see if you can improve your transfer speed, I used them and I can transfer from my Windows PC to my Linux Server a file about 1GB in size in a bout 1 min or less over WiFi.

```
#Backup original settings
sudo cp /etc/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf.orig

#Open file to apply samba speed tweaks
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf

#Locate and change the following lines in smb.conf
read raw = Yes
write raw = Yes
socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_SNDBUF=8192 SO_RCVBUF=8192
min receivefile size = 16384
use sendfile = true
aio read size = 16384
aio write size = 16384
```

Don't forget to save and close the file after you edit the above section.

For the socket option, you can also try these settings to compare which works best for you:

```
socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=131072 SO_SNDBUF=131072
```

Comment: None of the lines mentioned in your post are in my smb.conf file. Is it possible that I haven't technically finished the setup of samba and that there's some stuff left for me to do before even trying to modify the configuration file? So far what I did to share the HDD over the network was through the gui, selecting share this directory, selected my preferred option like guest access, and then Ubuntu told me to download Samba. Is there something else that I should be doing?

Comment: See comment on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/713360/16847) your buffer settings are not correct

Comment: I tried these, as well as other configurations, but it didn't work. Same situation with SSH as well. This isn't directly an answer to the question, but it's definitely a workaround; I switched to NFS, where the transfer speeds are a lot faster, for no obvious reason. For context, and I checked with iperf3, I'm able to get roughly 320 Mbps transfer speeds, which is well under the 480 Mbps USB 2.0 can handle. The only obvious bottleneck is Samba, and I'm not sure why.